# active record where method and not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. I know I can do:

```
Item.where(:color => 'red')
```

to get all red items, but how do I get all items whose color is not red?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a mix of the old school format and the new Arel format.

```
Item.where("color != ?", 'red')
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks a little clunky to me. What if I want to add conditions? For example size=2 and color != red

Comment: @pguardiario: Then you chain 'em up: `Item.where('color != ?', 'red').where(:size => 2)`.