# active record where not doesn't include nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This question builds on 
[active record where method and not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867457/active-record-where-method-and-not)

`Item.where("color != ?", 'red')`, or an analog with `.where.not` doesn't return nil values. How do I query to include those as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The underlying issue is how SQL databases make comparisons with NULL, not how Rails or ActiveRecord work. If you want records whose color is NULL, you have to explicitly include them with something like `where color IS NULL`.  NULL is not considered to be "not red".  Ultimately, to get what you want, you need an `or` in the SQL to cover both cases.

In ActiveRecord, you need this:

```
Item.where("color != ? or color is null", 'red')
```

You could also do this:

```
Item.where("color != ?", 'red').or(Item.where(color: nil))
```

Comment: I would add as example that `select 'red' != null;` returns `null` (so `select ('red' != null) is null;` returns `true`). A common way to discard `NULL`s is to use a default value for the column or use `COALESCE(color, '')` at the query time